# Scala Type Mismatch error when the function signature matches function call

Tags: scala

I'm quite new to Scala, but I believe I've written a completely legitimate Scala program:

This is on a Scala Worksheet:

```
  def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
    if (a > b) 1 // Not a 0 because the unit value of product is a 1
    else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)

  product(x => x * x)(3, 7)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
> <console>:8: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Unit
   required: Int
           if (a > b) 1 // Not a 0 because the unit value of product is a 1 else f
  (a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
           ^
> <console>:8: error: not found: value product
                product(x => x * x)(3, 7)
                ^
```

This is a simple product that multiplies all the squares of the numbers from `a` to `b` inclusive.

It says that there is something my function call, however, this should be completely legitimate, as I am passing a lambda function that does return an `Int`. Any help regarding this issue and how to deal with `type mismatch` errors would be deeply appreciated.

Using Scala `2.10.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worksheet is somehow mangling the body of `product` into one line, thus the `else` clause does not exist. Your code compiles and runs in the repl.

Comment: Dear lord, it works on repl, but does not work on the worksheet. Is the worksheet a bad thing to use, when learning Scala?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting braces around the method body:

```
def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
  if (a > b) 1
  else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
}
product(x => x * x)(3, 7)
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use repl you should enclose the body of your concrete function into braces like this:

```
def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    if (a > b) 1 // Not a 0 because the unit value of product is a 1
    else f(a) * product(f)(a + 1, b)
}

  product(x => x * x)(3, 7)
```

In other case scala repl only sees the definition of such function:

```
def product(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (a > b) 1
```

which is not correct